# Cygwin Dos2Unix Command not found

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I am having some problems using cygwin. I am trying to use the dos2unix utility and cygwin is throwing `-bash: dos2unix: command not found` When I go back into the installer and look through the packages I can't even find dos2unix, yet when I look at cygwin's package list it is clearly there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should find `dos2unix` in the category *Utils*, *Base*, or *Text*. It's easiest to use the search function.
If the package is not listed at all, try to use a different mirror.

If you installed this package while your cygwin terminal is still open, do a `rehash` (depends on you shell) or simply start a new terminal.

[image]

Comment: I tried a different mirror and it looks like the one I was previously downloading from simply didn't provide all of the packages. Thanks!

Comment: it is now in "text" rather than in Utils.

Comment: @user307279 : Thanks, I included it in my answer. With my current `setup.exe` the _dos2unix_ is located in _Base_, so it might differ, which version one is using.

Answer (score 10):

Additional option, may be helpful for someone:

To install additional packages in windows from **command line** you can use your **cygwin installer** (which you've downloaded to install cygwin, it's gui and all the stuff):

```
$ setup-x86_64.exe -q -P dos2unix
```

see this guide for details: 
http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that was due to me being extra stupid.  In my case, I have both 32 and 64 bits builds of Cygwin installed. I had installed "dos2unix" on the 32 bit version, but not installed it on the 64 bit version.  I couldn't understand why the installer seemed to work, but I still couldn't run it!

Advice - don't install both versions of Cygwin. :)

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cyg install dos2unix` if you are in the cygwin Terminal

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: @IndrajeetGour do you get any error? The post is quite old, I currently do not have `cygwin` on my `windows 10`. It [should](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/dos2unix.html) work as the package is updated in 2020.

Comment: Which package do I have to install to get `apt-cyg`?

Comment: @user1934428 do you work with `cygwin`? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16869816/1705829) is a solution using `wget` from `transcode-open`